# encodeURIComponent("x-men") doesn't work Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encodeuricomponent

I'm doing a ajax request

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "/search/" + encodeURIComponent("x-men")
}).done(function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

And this doesn't work well because it requests

> 127.0.0.1:8000/search/x-men

And this is wrong for browser.
You can give me a help . Please

Comment: How is that "wrong for browser"? What did you expect instead?

Comment: That result is expected assuming you're running this javascript on a page hosted on 127.0.0.1:8000. What is your intention?

Comment: I need that encodeURIComponent works because "-" character is a illegal char for the function.

Comment: Check this page, it says that "-" is illegal character
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: You are reading documentation wrong. Quote from english documentation: `encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

Comment: I'm sorry . The next time I'll read more carefully the documentation.